# How to get parameter from URL in PHP but after load page by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need get (date) parameter form URL by php but after load "step-02.php" by `.load` jQuery.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8000/selectRoom?hotelID=100&date=2016-11-08&night=5
```

I get the `2016-11-08` value from URL by php is `$_GET['date']` but after I load `step-02.php` with jQuery this code `$_GET['date']` does not work.

```
$(function () {
   $('#Step-01').hide();
   $('#Step-02').show();
   $('#Step-02').load('step_02.php');
})
```

HTML in `step-02.php`:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
   // This line gives an error and not work!
   <?php echo $_GET['date']; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use php `$_GET['date']` to get date parameter. You can parse URL in javascript and get target value.

Comment: @Mohammad Thank you Mohammad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http is stateless so unless you pass the date back in the ajax request, or save it to the session, the server has no way of remembering what you've told it previously.

Put this in step1.php somewhere

```
<input type="hidden" id="date-input" value="<?php echo $_GET['date']?>" />
```

Then do this:

```
$(function () {
  var date = $('#date-input').val();
  $('#Step-01').hide();
  $('#Step-02').show();
  $('#Step-02').load('step_02.php?date='+date);
})
```

Comment: Tank you for answer, but how to get `2016-01-01` form URL?

Comment: You don't need to get it from the URL, create a hidden input on the page in step1.php  <input id = "dateinput" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_Get['date']?>" />  You can then access it with Jquery and add it the URL you are loading

Comment: All you need to do is add it as a parameter to the AJAX call.  Once you do that, your existing code will work.  The reason it won't work is that there's no date parameter to echo if you're not sending it

Answer (score 2):

if i understand well at **first** you call this url , with these parameters : `http://localhost:8000/selectRoom?hotelID=100&date=2016-11-08&night=5`, that is why in your PHP file you can get the parameters , `$_GET['hotelID']`, `$_GET['date']` and `$_GET['night']` .

### When you call **step_02.php**

The url does not change to a new one , it remains as it was : `http://localhost:8000/selectRoom?hotelID=100&date=2016-11-08&night=5`, 
and that is the problem! The php file **step_02.php** , **did not** get any parameters from the client on the server request , so it does not recognise any parameter , **although** they are on the url.

### Solutions:

**A.** You can get the url by : `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` , which is going to give you all the url as it is, and by `explode("?", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` you are going to get the part of the url that has the parameters, after that you can use explode again..

**B.** you can pass the parameters you wish while you execute the ajax call to the server, and get them with `$_GET['parameter'`], like so:

```
data = {'hotelID':100,'date':2016-11-08,'night':5};
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url : url,
            type: "GET",
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                //load your spinner img
            },
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                //get response from server
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

### OR if it need be with load():

```
$('#Step-02').load('path', 'key=value');
```

Hope helps, good luck.

Comment: If you want to use $_GET, you shouldn't be using a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but I assume that you want to get the date value after load.

Use `callback()`

```
$('#Step-02').load('step_02.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: You should use parameter like `response` in function to get content of load.

Comment: Tank you so mush for answer, but i need get date parameter form url. but after load page by jQuery this code in `step-02.php` -> `$_GET['date'] is not work.

Comment: So when you're page `step-02.php` is ready you want to get load from that page only, right ?

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks for your feedback, I've updated my answer.

Comment: If you want to get the parameter of URL, you can direct do that in jQuery by using querystring, why you loading step2.php and get date there ?

Comment: @AmirHesari Don't forget to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){` wait till step2.php is gets ready and then you can get the contents from that file as response.

Comment: @Loading.. Thank you so much, How to add `$(document).ready(function(){` in `$('#Step-02').load('step_02.php',` ?

Comment: $(function(){}) is shorthand for $('document').ready(function(){}) so you're already doing it.